# Weak Version of Dirichlet's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was asked to prove the following: For any given $(a,b) = 1$ and $m > 0$ there are infinitely many integers $x$ such that $(a+bx,m) = 1$.

Now, I have a proof worked out that involves the following steps:

1) Prove that if one solution exists, then infinitely many do.

2) Then I show that there are solutions if $m$ is prime

3) Write $m= p_{1}^{e_{1}} \cdots p_{k}^{e_{k}}$. Then if a solution exists for 
$\overline{m} = p_{1}\cdots p_{k}$, then it holds for $m$ as well.

4) Let $m,n > 1$ and $(m,n) = 1$. Then if the claim holds for $m$ and $n$, it holds for $mn$ as well.

Finally, for a given $m$, apply (3) to reduce $m$ to a product of primes, repeatedly use (4) to reduce to individual primes, and then use (2) to prove the result.

While I think this proof works, I feel like there must be a better proof of this statement that isn't as complicated... Does anyone know of such a proof?

Comment: This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\gcd(a + bx, m) = \gcd (a + b(x+m), m) $. Hence, if one solution exists, then infinitely many do.

**Hint:** Let $x=1$ to $m$. Show that at least one solution must exist. This essentially boils down to $m > \phi(m) $.

Elaboration. Suppose that $ \gcd ( a + bx^* , m ) = m^* \neq 1 $. We must have $m^* \mid m$.
For how many values of $x$ do we have $m^* \mid \gcd( a + bx,m)$? This means that $\frac{a+bx}{m^*}$ is an integer. Clearly $ x = x^* + km^*$ will work. If any other value works, then we must have $ \gcd(a,b) > 1 $. Hence, there are $\frac{m}{m^*}$ such values that don't work.
Now, apply the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, to count the number of values of $x$ which don't work. Show that there are $\phi(m)$ values that don't work.

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure how the second hint boils down to $\phi(m) > 0$. I know you have to use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are coprime to guarantee a solution $1 < x < m$, but am not entirely sure how to proceed.

Comment: @BenPerez That is true, it should have been $\phi(m) < m$ instead.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I wanted to add that the conclusion isn't quite right. The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion yields that there are actually $\leq m-\phi(m)$ values which don't work and therefore at least $\phi(m)$ values which do work. You were correct originally when you said it boils down to $\phi(m)>0$.